# the If conditionals in the factory clashes functions keep on executing even if the condition is false

Tags: c++

this function is comparing and executing if conditionals even though they are false
it is supposed to be showing only one clash as the data has been hardcoded in the main function, it is supposed to show clash between task[0] and task[7] as hardcoded
this error is getting on my nerves now

```
int factory_clashes()
{
    //find out how many tasks are assigned to same factory at same time and same date
    //gene loop
    cout<<count<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if(j!=i)
            {
                if(Task[j].WorkshopID==Task[i].WorkshopID)
                {
                    if(Task[j].MachineID==Task[i].MachineID)
                    {
                        if(Task[j].StartDate.Day==Task[i].StartDate.Day)
                        {
                            if(Task[j].StartTime.Hours==Task[i].StartTime.Hours)
                            {
                                cout<<j<<" th value  "<<i<<" th iteration  "<<count<<endl;
                                count++;
                                cout<<count<<endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"CLASHES"<<endl<<count<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: You don't return an `int` from this function. It is undefined behavior to promise your compiler to return a value then break that promise. Your program is broken until at least you fix that bug.

Comment: You state this is C++, so could there be any strange operator overloading, e.g. [] or ==.  Also, whitespace helps with readability, which you utilize in your cout statements, but not in your code.

Comment: @drescherjm fixed, not working

Comment: @franji1 i don't know about that

Comment: It was just a stab in the dark.  Those operators are typically NOT overloaded.  They are probably NOT overloaded, but you said you don't know.  I would utilize a debugger and step through the code to see what the step-by-step behavior actually is.

Comment: @franji1 okay, let me try that too

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you with the current code and information. All we can do is take guesses and that does not really make a good question because the main purpose of a StackOverflow question is to help future readers with the same problem.